# How to not "compile" imported JSON file

Tags: json, typescript, tsc

I want to have a config file that my user can easily edit without needing to recompile the whole project . For now, in order to load my `config.json` I'm using `resolveJsonModule: true` in my `tsconfig.json`.

However, I'm still not sure if it has something to do with my project setup (`rootDir`, `outDir`, `includes`, etc...) but my typescript compiler "compiles" *a.k.a.* copies my `config.json` to the `outDir`, hence if my user edit the `config.json` in the root folder of my project it won't change anything.

#### Current setup

My `tsconfig.json`

```
    ...
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
    ...
```

Project structure:

```
.
├── config.json
├── src/
│    └── main.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

And my `main.ts`:

```js
import * as config from "../config.json";
```

What will happen now if I run `tsc` is that it will copy the `config.json` to the `dist` folder as follows:

```
dist/
├── config.json
└── src/
     └── main.js
```

#### Conclusion

So in my current setup, if the user compiles and then edit the `config.json` the project won't use his changes, since it's copied to the `dist` folder. What I want is to have the `config.json` file in my project root folder but my compiled javascript to still points to this same file.